# Ansible loop in items and then loop again with a module (nested loop)

Tags: ansible

I have a list of items in my playbook.

```
x_ssl_certs:
  - 'host1.domain.tld'
  - 'host2.domain.tld'
  - 'host3.domain.tld'
  - 'anotherhost.domain.tld'
```

Each of it has it's own SSL files, like `host1.domain.tld.key host1.domain.tld.crt host1.domain.tld.fullchain ...` and so on. Now I using this playbook to send out this files:

```
- name: Copy the {{ item }} key files
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}/{{ item }}.key"
    dest: '/etc/ssl/{{ item }}.key'
    owner: 'root'
    group: 'root'
    mode: '0644'
  loop: "{{ x_ssl_certs }}"

- name: Copy the {{ item }} crt files
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}/{{ item }}.crt"
    dest: '/etc/ssl/{{ item }}.crt'
    owner: 'root'
    group: 'root'
    mode: '0644'
  loop: "{{ x_ssl_certs }}"

- name: Copy the {{ item }} fullchain files
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}/{{ item }}.fullchain"
    dest: '/etc/ssl/{{ item }}.fullchain'
    owner: 'root'
    group: 'root'
    mode: '0644'
  loop: "{{ x_ssl_certs }}"
```

and so on, 1 task for every file. I would like to integrate this into one or two task, so it should lookup the `x_ssl_certs` list and send out each file which belongs to them. This files are the same naming convention for each item in the list.

This should be a loop in the loop, nested loop, or something like that, but based on the documentation it is not exactly clear for me how to make that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [*with_nested*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/nested_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-nested-lookup-composes-a-list-with-nested-elements-of-other-lists). For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Copy {{ item.0 }}.{{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ x_ssl_certs }}"
        - [key, crt, fullchain]
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Copy host1.domain.tld.key
  msg: Copy host1.domain.tld.crt
  msg: Copy host1.domain.tld.fullchain
  msg: Copy host2.domain.tld.key
  msg: Copy host2.domain.tld.crt
  msg: Copy host2.domain.tld.fullchain
  msg: Copy host3.domain.tld.key
  msg: Copy host3.domain.tld.crt
  msg: Copy host3.domain.tld.fullchain
  msg: Copy anotherhost.domain.tld.key
  msg: Copy anotherhost.domain.tld.crt
  msg: Copy anotherhost.domain.tld.fullchain
```

Comment: Thank you, I think now I understand the logic of `with_nested`. Based on the documentation I have translated `with_nested` to the new `loop` instead, it looks like this in this case: `loop: "{{ x_ssl_certs|product(['key', 'pem', 'fullchain'])|list }}"`

Comment: Right. The only [difference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian) is that [*nested*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/nested_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-nested-lookup-composes-a-list-with-nested-elements-of-other-lists) is a lookup plugin and [*product*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) is a filter. The results are the same.